# How to access taglib in scripts meant for run-script?

Tags: grails, taglib, grails-2.4, run-script

How to access ApplicationTagLib in a script meant for the grails command line run-script?

**In case someone wonders what is the use case**

This problem came up when I was trying to create a script for generating a json file (containing links to controllers and actions) for use in javascript files. More info in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763227/how-to-use-urls-rendered-as-javascript-variables-during-jasmine-unit-tests

I was considering using `g.createLink` in this script file but couldn't find how to use tag library in script file.

Comment: You can use below code to access your taglib 'def grailsApplication    def g = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib')'

Comment: @AnantKolvankar You should make that an answer.

Comment: I have posted it as a answer thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code to access your taglib

```
def grailsApplication 
def g = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.ta‌​glib.ApplicationTagLib')
```